# [Firebase Analytics - Selective tracking of screens

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I have a react native app for ios and android. 
Is it possible disable auto tracking of certain activities and viewcontrollers?

Like for example in my android app, I have 4 activities there and I want to track 2 only.

Answer (score 0):

In On Resume method of an activity where you need to set track give Firebase Analytics tracking with some reference and on the other don't keep for the activities you don't want. this is the way you have to track id in onResume method.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (getActivity() != null)
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity()).setCurrentScreen(getActivity(), "Notifications", getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```